# Scottish Letter Equation

Tags: mathematics, alphametic

The following puzzle is from a Scottish mathematical competition and has been posed at the Jordanhill school in Glasgow: A shop sells letter signs, and the price of every letter is an integer number of pennies.

- The letters of the word ONE cost 1 pound sterling.
- The letters of the word TWO cost 2 pound sterling.
- The letters of the word FOUR cost 4 pound sterling.
- The letters of the word ELEVEN cost 11 pound sterling.

What's the price of the letters of the word TWELVE?

Comment: This is very close to a pure maths problem IMO.

Comment: @boboquack I think the very cute answer justifies the mathiness!

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 9):

Well:

> TWELVE=ELEVEN-EN+TW

Which is:

> ELEVEN-ONE+TWO (because the O's cancel out and rearranging letters doesn't do anything)

Which is:

> £11-£1+£2=£12

So:

> FOUR=£4 is a red herring

Comment: Heh, so it again equals the number? I wonder how many other numbers this applies for...

Comment: @Weckar I think this is just a one-off, because ELEVEN PLUS TWO = TWELVE PLUS ONE in letters as well as numbers - I can't find a similar thing for other numbers.

Comment: It applies for SIX.

Comment: @Ian how so? Is it something to do with the teens?